# How do I find this angle?

Tags: geometry, angle

[image]

Okay, I know the angles next to $115^{\circ}$ are supplementary to it, so the angles are $65^{\circ}$. I subtracted $65$ and $30$ from $180$ to get to measure angle of $85^{\circ}$. How can I find $e$ this way? Do I use alternate or supplementary angles?

Comment: $\angle 85^\circ=\angle 34^\circ+e$, so $e=51^\circ$.

Comment: Well the title seems to be misleading.  I think you must change the title something suitable to the question.

Comment: The sum of the interior angles of this quadrilateral must be $360^{\circ}$. We have $e+30^{\circ}+(115+2\cdot 65)^{\circ}+34^{\circ}=360^{\circ}$. Can you take it from here? You can also consider on of the triangles.

Comment: Thank you, @Fakemistake. Your comment does help with my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a triangle, sum of two interior angles is equal to the exterior angle that has no neighbourhood to the interior angles summed up. So we have
$$34^\circ+e = 85^\circ \implies e = 51^\circ$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Look at the triangle having the angles $e$ and $34^\circ$. The third angle in that triangle should be easy to calculate, then use the fact that the sum of the angles is $180^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the supplement of 85°, which is 95°. Now you can find the other angle of the triangle that has angles 65° and 34°, which is 81°, and then take its supplement (99°). Now
$$e+99^\circ+115^\circ+95^\circ=360^\circ$$
$$e=51^\circ$$

Comment: How to write in latex